# Delete columns containing only NA with data table

Tags: r, data.table

Is there a better way than

```
DT <- DT[,!apply(DT,2,function(x) all(is.na(x))), with = FALSE]
```

to subset with data table only on columns which are not entirely filled with `NA`s?

Thanks

Comment: I would go with `for (j in copy(names(DT))) if(all(is.na(DT[[j]]))) set(DT, j = j, value = NULL)`

Comment: @DavidArenburg what's the point of copying the names?

Comment: @MichaelChirico because the names are being modified in place. Try running it without the `copy`.

Answer (score 7):

The basic idea is to find the all-`NA` columns with something like:

```
na_idx = sapply(DT, function(x) all(is.na(x)))
```

To apply this to subsetting your table, the answer depends on whether you'd like to remove these columns from your table, or whether you plan to create a separate, derivative table;

In the former case, you should set these columns to `NULL`:

```
DT[ , which(sapply(DT, function(x) all(is.na(x)))) := NULL]
```

In the latter case, there are several options:

```
idx = sapply(DT, function(x) !all(is.na(x)))
DT = DT[ , idx, with = FALSE] # or DT = DT[ , ..idx]

DT = DT[ , lapply(.SD, function(x) if (all(is.na(x))) NULL else x)]
```

`apply` and `colSums` approaches will involve matrix conversion which is likely to be inefficient.

Here's a benchmark of the cases laid out here and by @DavidArenburg in the comments above:

```
          method   time
1: which := NULL  1.434
2:  for set NULL  3.432
3:   lapply(.SD) 16.041
4:         ..idx 10.343
5:    with FALSE  4.896
```

Code:

```
library(data.table)

NN = 1e7
kk = 50
n_na = 5

set.seed(021349)
DT = setDT(replicate(kk, rnorm(NN), simplify = FALSE))
DT[ , (sample(kk, n_na)) := NA_real_]

DT2 = copy(DT)

t1 = system.time(
  DT2[ , which(sapply(DT2, function(x) all(is.na(x)))) := NULL]
)

rm(DT2)
DT2 = copy(DT)

t2 = system.time({
  for (col in copy(names(DT2))) 
    if (all(is.na(DT2[[col]]))) set(DT2, , col, NULL)
})

rm(DT2)
DT2 = copy(DT)

t3 = system.time({
  DT3 = DT2[ , lapply(.SD, function(x) if (all(is.na(x))) NULL else x)]
})

rm(DT3)

t4 = system.time({
  idx = sapply(DT2, function(x) !all(is.na(x)))
  DT3 = DT2[ , ..idx]
})

rm(DT3)

t5 = system.time({
  idx = sapply(DT2, function(x) !all(is.na(x)))
  DT3 = DT2[ , idx, with = FALSE]
})

data.table(
  method = c('which := NULL', 'for set NULL', 
             'lapply(.SD)', '..idx', 'with FALSE'),
  time = sapply(list(t1, t2, t3, t4, t5), `[`, 'elapsed')
)
```

Comment: I think `idx = sapply(DT, function(x) all(is.na(x))) ; DT[ , which(idx) := NULL]` would be a bit more idiomatic

Comment: @DavidArenburg depends on whether you'd like to create a new table or not, I guess

Comment: You suggested `DT = DT[ , ..idx]` which is overriding the same table, so I though it would be better to assign `NULL` instead. Also the `..id` basically runs `with = FALSE` which is better avoided.

Comment: Given the use-case is likely to involve columns where *some but not all* the values are NA, it is considerably faster to use `sapply(.SD, function(x) anyNA(x) && all(is.na(x)))` to avoid checking columns that are clearly not `NA`.

Comment: @Hugh that's some fine data engineering there

Comment: That's why they pay me the big bucks